# How to change AppCompatButton menu item text

Tags: java, android, android-view, menuitem, android-menu

I'm using the following layout for my menu

```
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <item android:id="@+id/button"
        android:title="off"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton"
        tools:text="OFF"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
</menu>
```

There doesn't seem to be an obvious way to set text to the button. The following two lines I added did not result in any visible text being added to the button.

```
tools:text="OFF"
android:textColor="@android:color/white"
```

**edit:**

To be clear, this a menu item, but the action view class is `AppCompatButton` and I want to set text to it.

Comment: are you talking about buttons or menus?

Comment: Well it's a menu item but the action view class is AppCompatButton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the action view from `MenuItem`, and perform necessary changes there:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.button);
    AppCompatButton button = (AppCompatButton) menuItem.getActionView();
    button.setText("My Button");
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like this also works in the `onCreateOptions` method

Comment: It will, but `onCreateOptionsMenu()` is for creating a menu, and `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` is for preparing (updating) menu. The former will be called once, the latter may be called multiple times depending on whether menu has been changed.